# Inline math rendering when using pelican and liquid tags

Tags: javascript, mathjax, pelican

`liquid_tags` fails to render inline math for me. I managed to have inline math rendered properly when using "plain" markdown. See for example [this example](http://drorata.github.io/posts/2017/Jan/13/first-post/) with sources available [here](https://github.com/drorata/drorata.github.io/blob/source/content/first-post.md).

However, inline math in a Jupyter notebook is not rendered properly even though it does look OK inside the Jupyter environment. An example can be found in the following places:

- [The rendered post](http://drorata.github.io/posts/2017/Mar/07/minimal-example-with-linear-regression/)
- [Markdown source](https://github.com/drorata/drorata.github.io/blob/source/content/linear-regression-minimal-example.md)
- [The notebook's source](https://github.com/drorata/drorata.github.io/blob/source/content/notebooks/linear-regression-minimal-example.ipynb)

As you can see, Github renders the inline math properly, but when included in a post, this breaks. I failed to understand where the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update 1:**
It seems like the function `init_mathjax()` is not executed when the `HTML` page is loaded. If I run it manually from the page's console, the inline math is rendered properly.

PS: I posted this also as an issue on the project's GitHub ([link](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins/issues/933))

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: In `Pelican-plugins/liquid_tags/notebook.py` replace

```
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"></script>
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"></script>
```

It seems like the problem is due to [this commit](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins/commit/be9e98b897e5ce6febe42745893c06f9c7175312) where async loading of MathJax was introduced. I fixed/reverted it in [my fork](https://github.com/drorata/pelican-plugins/commit/e08da7cbeab485e16bf65fe1fd2481c2d09d2ae1) and now rendering of inline math works as expected.